# Jira 6 groovy error

Tags: groovy, jira, jira-plugin

Use the Jira 6. sometimes groovy script error.

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.api.User;
import com.atlassian.jira.user.ApplicationUser;
passesCondition = true
String currentUser = ComponentAccessor.getJiraAuthenticationContext().getUser().getUsername()
if (currentUser != issue.getProjectObject().getLeadUserName())
passesCondition = false
```

Log Error:

```
2015-04-16 17:30:28,842 http-bio-8080-exec-13076 ERROR zeynep 1050x1610767x2 gf80de 10.130.12.70 /secure/CommentAssignIssue.jspa [scriptrunner.jira.workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction] Script function failed on issue: KUR-3666, actionId: 811, file: null
java.lang.Exception: Class C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA 4.0.1\groovy_scripts\is_project_lead.gy could not be found, or could not be compiled
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl.ensureScriptCompiled(ScriptRunnerImpl.groovy:554)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl.validateAndRunCannedInternal(ScriptRunnerImpl.groovy:365)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl.this$2$validateAndRunCannedInternal(ScriptRunnerImpl.groovy)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl$this$2$validateAndRunCannedInternal.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunnerImpl.runCanned(ScriptRunnerImpl.groovy:342)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.ScriptRunner$runCanned$5.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.jira.workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction.run(ScriptWorkflowFunction.groovy:80)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.jira.workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction$run$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.onresolve.scriptrunner.jira.workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction.passesCondition(ScriptWorkflowFunction.groovy:28)
```

Comment: is the file `C:\Program Files\Atlassian\JIRA 4.0.1\groovy_scripts\is_project_lead.gy` there and is this the file in question?  why is it in a jira4 directory and you are talking about jira6?

Comment: this way in path. Because jira 4 to 6 update. We can not change the file path. But I am sure that the existence of the file